# Is there a way for other classes to recognize a public variable in another class?

Tags: actionscript-3, global-variables

The coding language I am using is AS3 with flash Develop. What I am trying to do is to allow the class Chapter to access a public variable in the class Main Menu. The variable is named YesNo and when I try to access it in the class Chapter it doesn't work. I had downloaded something called Flashpunk that came with presets for multiple different classes that helps with making games, I will show my Code below.

Main Menu

```
package 
{
    import net.flashpunk.Entity;
    import net.flashpunk.graphics.Image;
    import net.flashpunk.utils.Input;
    import net.flashpunk.utils.Key;
    import net.flashpunk.FP;

    public class MainMenu extends Entity
    {

        [Embed(source = "net/MainScreen.png")]
        private const SPRITE1:Class;

        private var sprite1:Image = new Image(SPRITE1);

        public var YesNo:int = 0

        public function MainMenu() 
        {
            graphic = sprite1;
            sprite1.centerOrigin();

            x = 200
            y = 150

            layer = 150
        }


        override public function update():void
        {
            if (Input.pressed(Key.DIGIT_1))
            {
                YesNo = YesNo + 1
            }

            if (Input.pressed(Key.DIGIT_2))
            {
                YesNo = YesNo + 2
            }
        }




    }

}
```

Chapter

```
package 
{
    import net.flashpunk.Entity;
    import net.flashpunk.World;

    public class Chapter extends World
    {

        public function Chapter() 
        {
            add(new MainMenu())

        }


    }

}
```

Comment: Your `Chapter` code doesn't reference `YesNo` at all.   Plus, please describe what isn't working - do you get an error? an unexpected result?  Nothing happens at all?

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis when i try to reference YesNo in the chapter class is comes up with the error Access of undefined property YesNo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you likely need to do is this:

```
public class Chapter extends World
{
    //create a class level var that you can access anywhere in this class
    public var mainMenu:MainMenu;

    public function Chapter() 
    {
        //instantiate your menu class and assign it to the class level var
        mainMenu = new MainMenu();

        add(mainMenu);

        //access the menu's public properties and functions like this:
        mainMenu.YesNo = 0; //or whatever you need to do with that var.
    }


}
```